# How to align col content horizontally in Ant Design React components?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I need to align col content to center horizontally. I looked ant documentation but could not came up with a solution.

What I tried is :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved problem by adding "type" and "align" properties to Col component.

```
  <Row>
    <Col span={8} style={{backgroundColor:'red'}} type="flex" align="middle" >
      Col
    </Col>
    <Col span={4} style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
      Col
    </Col>
  </Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get ride of this problem by adding  CSS property  "justifyContent : center" to col component.

```
<Row>
    <Col  style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'end'}}></Col>
    <Col  style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}></Col>
</Row>
```